# Json on data-attribute

Tags: javascript, html, json, custom-data-attribute

Hi everyone I have a json in a data attribute and I have to take the data that is inside, I can get the string inside the data attribute but I can't get access to the object.

This is my code:

HTML

```
<a data-password="{Show:'Show', Hide:'Hide'}">Show</a>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("a[data-password]").click(function(e) {
        var lJson = $(this).attr("data-password");

        console.log(lJson);

        lJson2 = JSON.parse(lJson);

        console.log(lJson2.Hide);
    });

});
```

Comment: This is not valid JSON - you need to use double quotes around the values *and* the keys.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that the JSON inside of your data attribute is not properly [stringified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

The stringified version should look like `{"Show":"Show", "Hide":"Hide"}` with the keys and string values inside double quotes.

Try this example below for the working version:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("a[data-password]").click(function(e) {
        var lJson = $(this).attr("data-password");

        console.log(lJson);

        lJson2 = JSON.parse(lJson);

        console.log(lJson2.Hide);
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a data-password='{"Show":"Show", "Hide":"Hide"}'>Show</a>
```